# Adding list of values in a value and key pair in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary as below:

`{'a':[(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(0,2),(0,3)]}`

So now I would like to obtain it in this way:

`{'a':[(3,1),(0,2),(0,3)]}`

So specifically I want to take the second element in the value list to be `grouped by` and the first element in the value list to give its sum.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, I think your want your dictionary to be `{a: [(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(0,2),(0,3)]}` instead, yours is not correctly formatted.

Comment: Yeah formatted it now. I am not sure how to do it. I tried doing adding all the first element values : ```Output={}                                                                               
                                for x,y in vs:
                                 Output[y]=Output[y]+x                                                         
                                 return (k,Output)```. But this is giving me a Keyerror 1

Comment: @TippabhatlaNiharika, you should be adding essential information such as code, expected output, etc. in the question and not in comments

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dic = {'a': [(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(0,2),(0,3)]}

newdic = {}
for k, v in dic.items():
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for vv in v:
        d[vv[1]] += vv[0]
    newdic[k] = [(v, k) for k, v in d.items()]
print(newdic)
# {'a': [(3, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = {"a":[(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(0,2),(0,3)]}

for k, l in dictionary.items():
    # have a temporary dictionary for each list
    temp_dictionary = dict()

    # for each tuple value, add the associated keys
    for tuple_k, tuple_v in l:
        # get(key, default_value_if_key_not_found)
        temp_dictionary[tuple_v] = temp_dictionary.get(tuple_v, 0) + tuple_k

    # replace the list in the original dictionary
    dictionary[k] = [(tuple_v, tuple_k) for (tuple_k, tuple_v) in temp_dictionary.items()]

print(dictionary)
# {a:[(3,1),(0,2),(0,3)]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..!this did the job too..!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tuples in the arrays are ordered (or at least grouped) by the second value, you could use the groupby function from itertools to do the transformation:

```
from itertools import groupby

def group(tuples):
    return [ (sum(next(zip(*ts))),k) for k,ts in groupby(tuples,key=lambda t:t[1])]

d  = { "a":[(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(0,2),(0,3)] }
d2 = { key:group(tuples) for key,tuples in d.items() }

# d2: {'a': [(3, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)]}
```

if not, you'll have to sort them in the group function using:

```
tuples = sorted(tuples,key=lambda t:t[1])
```